# Route to specific path with React Router V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some ids that I want to route to (react router). I have a template and the components will be rendered with different types of information based on the id. I watched this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4kqMQorcnE but I cant seem to get it to work.

Here’s the `Link`:

```
<Link to={`/log/${item._id}`}>
  <p
    className="sub-title-text-container"
    style={{
      fontWeight: '300',
      textDecoration: 'underline'
    }}
  >
    Se logg
  </p>
</Link>
```

In the same file almost at the bottom I have this:

```
<Route path="/log/:item._id" component={DoorDetails} />
```

And my component `DoorDetails`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const DoorDetails = ({ match }) =>
  <div>
    {match.params.item._id}
    <h1>Yes</h1>
  </div>
```

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: I would say try `<Route path="/log/:id" component={DoorDetails} />`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for replying, but that didn't do it! :P

Comment: is `_id` a key in item object

Comment: What's your exact problem, the Link doesn't work? You can access the dynamic `id` in the route?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes it is.

Comment: @Jayce444 The URL updates, but it wont redirect me to the other component.

Comment: So the page doesn't change at all? No errors in the console?

Comment: @Jayce444 no, it does not change and there is no errors.

Comment: Ok so wait you said that that _id is a key in an object. I'm not sure how you're setting it up and naming things, but all it should be is like this:  `<Route path='/potato/:id component={Potato}/>` and then in your Potato component should just be accessed like so: `render(){return(<div>{this.props.params.id}</div>)'}`. I've done that exact code in my apps and it works so it might be the way you're using an object key as part of the dynamic route parameter

Comment: Something I noticed was that when I past this in my url: `http://localhost:3000/log/595a04a4247588e73dca1928` I get my console log to display in the developer console. But when clicking the link and my URL changes there is no console log.

Comment: well navigating to a route programmatically (i.e. pushing the route into the browserHistory in some function) and manually navigating there by entering it in the URL bar or by refreshing the page aren't the same. Check out server-side vs. client-side routing in React Router